# How do I initialize values from CoreData when it's initialized and then make them accessible throughout the app

Tags: swift, core-data

I am having a challenge initializing values from CoreData entity when my app opens. I would like to set them after the persistence container is initialized. I saw [this video](https://youtu.be/BPQkpxtgalY?si=XmWAAwWT9ERo5DxH&t=822) that uses MVVM, which I'm not using, but show how to run a fetch right after CoreData is initialized. I adapted it for sake of example:

```
class CoreDataViewModel: ObservableObject {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var defaultEntity?: FruitEntity = nil

    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "FruitsContainer")

        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                print("successfully loaded PersistentStores")
            }
        }
    setDefaultCase()

    }

    func fetchFruits() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<FruitEntity>(entityName: "FruitEntity")
    
         do {
            defaultEntity = try container.viewContext.fetch(request).first
        
        } catch let error {
            print("ERROR fetching: \(error)")
            defaultEntity = nil
        }
    }

}
```

The problem is that I was using this code from [this video](https://youtu.be/bvm3ZLmwOdU?si=nKjPQUAUvJTv0OUa&t=610) to set the managedObjectContext as an EnvrionmentObject so I could use it in any view in which I might need it:

```
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
    }
```

The savedEntities object in this example would be the object I would like to access everywhere in my application, but I also need to use the managedObjectContext everywhere I need it by simply calling:

```
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
```

and use the default entity like:

```
if defaultEntity != nil {
    FirstView()
} else {
    SecondView()
}
```

Does a delegate make sense here? If there is a 2nd object I need to create at some point after the database is initialized would a delegate help with that too?

Comment: Why not set the whole CoreDataViewModel as an environment object as well?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson would that mean I am pushing the CoreDataViewModel into an environment variable as well as a child of it as well? Does it remain just one object with two different references?

Comment: In a way but you could split it into two types if you want.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I did what you said in your first comment. If you want to add it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CoreDataViewModel conforms to ObservableObject so you can use it as an EnvironmentObject and have access to it in all your views.

```
@StateObject var coreDataViewModel = CoreDataViewModel()

WindowGroup {
    ContentView()
        .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
        .environmentObject(coreDataViewModel)
}
```